Initializing Stripe in a FlutterFlow Web App
This is a specific question about Stripe+FlutterFlow (not just flutter).
I'm trying to initialize Stripe in my Flutterflow project, and I believe the right place to do it is by using the main.dart file.
In that file, I'm inserting a custom action with this code:
/ Automatic FlutterFlow imports
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_theme.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_util.dart';
import '/custom_code/actions/index.dart'; // Imports other custom actions
import '/flutter_flow/custom_functions.dart'; // Imports custom functions
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// Begin custom action code
// DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY THE CODE ABOVE!

import 'package:flutter_stripe/flutter_stripe.dart';

Future initializeStripe() async {
  Stripe.publishableKey =
      'my_key';
  Stripe.merchantIdentifier = 'merchant.flutter.stripe.test';
  Stripe.urlScheme = 'flutterstripe';
  await Stripe.instance.applySettings();
}

BUT, when starting the Web App in Debug mode it hangs. I know it's this bit because if I remove the call to this action while initializing it works.
I'm not an expert in either dart or Stripe or Flutterflow. Someone can help?

Did you add flutter_stripe_web to your pubspec file? flutter_stripe_web is required if you want to use Stripe with a Flutter Web app.

Thank you, that worked. But the issue now is I'm trying to launch Stripe Payment sheet on a Web app, and I'm receiving the error 'initPaymentSheet' not supported in Web. So what's the way to present the payment Sheet and capture card details in FlutterFlow Web?

PaymentSheet is only available in mobile and you can't use it in web. Instead you should PaymentElement. Check example code here: https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe/blob/main/example/lib/screens/payment_sheet/payment_element/platforms/payment_element_web.dart
